# How to get the data source for an AWS CloudFront Origin Access Identity in Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

We have terraform code in another project that must remain in that separate project that creates three AWS CloudFront Origin Access Identities - one that we want to use for all of our qa environments, one for all of our pprd environments, and one for all of our prod environments.

In another project, how can I use Terraform to get the datasource for these to use them in creating a CloudFront distribution with Terraform?

Does the datasource have to use the OAI ID or name to filter on and how? What happens if the OAI changes. I guess what I am getting at is I would prefer to avoid hard coding the ID or name if possible - Or is that the only way to do this?

We have three OAI's that we will need to use separately - In other words, we will be creating multiple qa distributions that will use the qa OAI, multiple pprd distributions that will use the pprd OAI, and multiple prod distributions that will use the prod OAI.

Let's assume that the ID's are  AAAAAAA for the qa one, BBBBBBBB for the pprd one, and CCCCCCC for the prod one (blurred out the real ones in case there is a security issue in posting them).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the Origin Access Identity created by another stack. In fact there are multiple ways to get it.

The easiest way would be to use a [`aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_origin_access_identity) data source. You can define a data source as follows:

```
data "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "example" {
  id = "EDFDVBD632BHDS5"
}
```

The `id` is the identifier of the distribution. For the attribute references of the data block, you would want to check out the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_origin_access_identity#attributes-reference).

> What happens if the OAI changes?

The data block assumes that the resource already exists in AWS and was created outside of the current state. This means that it will be refreshed every time you do a `terraform plan`. If something changes on the resource, it will be detected at the next plan.

> I guess what I am getting at is I would prefer to avoid hard coding the ID or name if possible.

In case of a data block, you have to provide the ID somehow. This can be either using a variable or hard-coding it. Now, if you really want to avoid this, you can use another method for importing remote resources.

The other option would be to read from a Terraform [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data) by having a `terraform_remote_state` data source. This option is a bit more complex, since the remote state has to expose attributes as [`outputs`](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs). Also, you have to provide the location of the remote state, so can also be considered a hardcoded value.

Comment: But if the ID changes for some reason (the OAI is deleted and recreated) then the datasource will be broken correct?

Comment: The ID is not something that can change. Certainly, the resource could be removed, in which case the plan will fail, but this is something that can happen in any case when you depend on something outside of the current state.